# How to make a complex batch read query using DynamoDB enhanced client?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm using the DynamoDB enhanced client for Java.

I have a DynamoDB table where partition key is `S: product_id` and sort key is `S: created_date`.

I have a list of IDs `List<ProductId>`.

I want to get all items from the table where `product_id` is in `List<ProductId>` and since `created_date > someDate`.

So, for example if I have items like

```json
[
  {
    "product_id": "aaa",
    "created_date": "2023-04-01T22:57:12.942Z"
  },
  {
    "product_id": "bbb",
    "created_date": "2023-04-02T22:57:12.942Z"
  },
  {
    "product_id": "aaa",
    "created_date": "2023-01-03T22:57:12.942Z"
  },
  {
    "product_id": "ccc",
    "created_date": "2023-04-03T22:57:12.942Z"
  },
  {
    "product_id": "bbb",
    "created_date": "2023-04-01T22:57:12.942Z"
  }
]
```

my `List<ProductId>` is `["aaa", "bbb"]`, `someDate` is `2023-04-01T22:57:12.942Z`, then I want to get back

```json
[
  {
    "product_id": "aaa",
    "created_date": "2023-04-02T22:57:12.942Z"
  },
  {
    "product_id": "bbb",
    "created_date": "2023-04-02T22:57:12.942Z"
  },
  {
    "product_id": "bbb",
    "created_date": "2023-04-03T22:57:12.942Z"
  }
]
```

How do I achieve this with the DynamoDB enhanced client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DynamoDB you cannot do a `BatchGetItem` without providing the entire primary key (partition and sort key) for each item. So your use case where you want greater than `created_date` will not work.

If you do know the entire key, you can use this [code example](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/blob/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/java/WorkingWithItems/BatchGetItem.java) to help get you started.